# ember JS returns only the last value from tastypie

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, tastypie

I'm trying to get a list of items served from Django and Tastypie and display them using Ember.js. I've encountered the following problem:

EmberJS stores only the last value from JSON - so /api/post serves a few entries, but EmberJS stores and then displays only the last one(I also checked with the Ember extensions for Chrome). I'm not even sure where to look for a solution - is it Ember, Ember-data, Tastypie or all of them?

Here's the javascript code:

```
Blog.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoTastypieAdapter.extend({
   host: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
   namespace: "api/v1"
});

Blog.ApplicationSerializer = DS.DjangoTastypieSerializer.extend({});

/* Models */
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   body: DS.attr('string'),
   added: DS.attr('date'),
   created: DS.attr('date')
});

/* Routes */
Blog.Router.map(function() {
   this.route('post-list');
   this.route('post', { path: 'post_id' });
});

Blog.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('post-list')
    }
});

Blog.PostListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post')
    }
});
```

Here's the curl extract for reference:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "added": "2014-12-23T19:49:28.881759",
      "body": "hsdkfkjahsdkshufy \r\n\r\nLorem ipsum",
      "created": "2014-12-23T19:49:28.881759",
      "id": 2,
      "resource_uri": "\/api\/v1\/post\/2",
      "slug": "jklshfkjasfhkjkhlf",
      "title": "jkl;shfkjasfhkjkhlf"
    },
    {
      "added": "2014-12-23T23:00:23.719586",
      "body": "sdhkjasgaskg slkhs;fas\r\n\r\nhsdkjhsask sfhjask \r\nhakjhagkl\r\n\r\nhgaskjhagskj \r\nhgkjash",
      "created": "2014-12-23T23:00:23.719586",
      "id": 3,
      "resource_uri": "\/api\/v1\/post\/3",
      "slug": "asfhklasdnhjasdkghskl",
      "title": "asfhklasdnhjasdkghskl"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the project using latest Django version (from 1.6 to 1.7). It seems that the issue is solved now, no changes in the code were made.